# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-51-generic x86_64) freezes daily

Tags: 18.04, kernel, vmware

I am running a headless Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Media Server. I upgraded it many moons ago from 16 and the server has been rock solid for a very long time. In the past month or so, the machine becomes completely unresponsive. IE No pings, SSH and if I go to the console (Running in ESXI) I can see some CUPS errors on screen but also can not get it to respond to direct keyboard inputs. The only option left is to reset the machine via VMWare.

If I look in /var/log/syslog it gives no real clues.
In /var/log/kern.log I see a massive gap in logs from when I reset the server:

- Jun  9 18:19:08 BINSVR3 canonical-livepatch[1778]: Client.Check Jun 
  9 18:19:08 BINSVR3 canonical-livepatch[1778]: Checking with livepatch
  service.

  - Jun  9 18:19:09 BINSVR3 canonical-livepatch[1778]: updating
    last-check
  - Jun  9 18:19:09 BINSVR3 canonical-livepatch[1778]: touched
    last check
  - Jun  9 18:19:09 BINSVR3 canonical-livepatch[1778]: No
    updates available at this time.
  - Jun  9 18:19:09 BINSVR3
    canonical-livepatch[1778]: No payload available.
  - Jun 12 07:48:10
    BINSVR3 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.0-51-generic
    (buildd@lgw01-amd64-059) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3))
    55-Ubuntu SMP $
  - Jun 12 07:48:10 BINSVR3 kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.15.0-51-generic
    root=/dev/mapper/BINSVR3--vg-root ro
  - Jun 12 07:48:10 BINSVR3 kernel:
    [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
  - Jun 12 07:48:10 BINSVR3 kernel:
    [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
  - Jun 12 07:48:10 BINSVR3 kernel: [
    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
  - Jun 12 07:48:10 BINSVR3 kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
  - Jun 12 07:48:10 BINSVR3 kernel: [    0.000000] Disabled fast string operations

If anybody can assist, that would be great.

Hardware Hypervisor:
Dell T320
6 CPUs x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2430 0 @ 2.20GHz
Memory: 31.96 GB
Datastore: 7TB
ESXi-6.5.0-4564106-standard (VMware, Inc.)

VM Hardware:
4vCPU's
8GB RAM
4TB HDD's
Currently running at 64mhz / 3gb RAM utilisation

Comment: what exact hardware do you have? please edit your post to include this information

Comment: Edited as per your request.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by part number, but this is my own local VM on my own hardware in my house.